# print multiple values for each key in a dictionary on a new line, preceded by the key

Tags: python, list

In Python, I have two lists, `ids` and `gos` and both have the same length (i.e. equal number of lines), but gos can have multiple elements per line (i.e., it is a list of lists) while ids has only 1 element per line

For example:

```
ids =  ['1','2','3']
gos =  [['a','b','c'],['d', 'e'], ['f']]
```

I want to print out each id in ids as many times as there are go-elements in the gos list followed by one of the corresponding elements from gos list, and each time on a new line.

I hope this clarifies the output I am seeking:

```
'1'   'a'
'1'   'b'
'1'   'c'
'2'   'd'
'2'   'e'
'3'   'f'
```

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use zip:

```
for i,g in zip(ids, gos):
   for ge in g:
      print i,ge
```

output:

```
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 d
2 e
3 f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these simple *nested* for loops:

```
for i, e1 in enumerate(ids):
    for e2 in gos[i]:
        print e1, e2
```

**Output:**

```
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 d
2 e
3 f
```

**Note:** The [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function is used to keep count of the index, which will be used to access to the corresponding element of `gos`.

Answer (score 0):

another way of doing this

```
from itertools import product,imap
ids =  ['1','2','3']
gos =  [['a','b','c'],['d', 'e'], ['f']]

for i in imap(product,ids,gos):
    for j in i:
        print j[0],j[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way of doing it..

```
ids = "1 2 3".split()
gos = ['a b c'.split(), 'c d'.split(), ['f']]

import itertools

ig = [zip([i] * len(g), g)
      for i, g in zip(ids, gos)]

for i, g in itertools.chain.from_iterable(ig):
    print(i, g)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is an easy way to do that

```
for i in range(len(gos)):
    for k in gos[i]:
        print ids[i], k
```

Output

```
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 d
2 e
3 f
```